# Can interface without implementation be autowired in service class in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I watched a spring tutorial video on youtube [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_Jnu_jHfQbM&list=PLmbC-xnvykcghOSOJ1ZF6ja3aOgZAgaMO&index=31) in which he did not implemented  `public interface TopicRepository extends CrudRepository<Topic, String>`
still he was able to run the application by writing

```
@Autowired
private TopicRepository topicRepository;
```

in service class, but when I try the same I get an error like:

> Field topicRepository in
> io.spring.springbootstarter.topic.TopicService required a bean of type
> 'io.spring.springbootstarter.topic.TopicRepository' that could not be
> found.
>
> The injection point has the following annotations:
>
> - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)
>
> Action:
>
> Consider defining a bean of type
> 'io.spring.springbootstarter.topic.TopicRepository' in your
> configuration.

I am new to spring and i am using spring 2.3.1

```
package io.spring.springbootstarter.topic;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

public interface TopicRepository extends CrudRepository<Topic, String>{


   //getTopics()
   //getTopic(String id)
  //deleteTopic(String id)
  //updateTopic(Topic t)

}
```

in below class i am creating object

```
package io.spring.springbootstarter.topic;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class TopicService {


@Autowired
private TopicRepository topicRepository;

public List<Topic> getAllTopics(){
    
    List<Topic> topics=new ArrayList<Topic>();
    topicRepository.findAll().forEach(topics::add);
     return topics;
}

public Optional<Topic> getTopic(String id) {
    
    return topicRepository.findById(id);
}


public void addTopic(Topic topic) {
    topicRepository.save(topic);
    
}

public void updateTopic(String id , Topic topic) {
    topicRepository.save(topic);
    
    
}

public void deleteTopic(String id) {
    topicRepository.deleteById(id);
    
    
    
    }


  }
```

Answer (score 3):

Interfaces extending `CrudRepository` are implemented (auto-generated) by Spring by using the [Spring Expression Language](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.3.10.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html). The auto-generated classes are spring-beans and thus can be autowired.

You can find more information about Spring Data Repositories in the [Official Spring Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-commons/docs/1.6.1.RELEASE/reference/html/repositories.html).

Comment: Thank you for the clarification and the reference ,so it means we can autowire an interface extending CrudRepository. but still i am facing the same problem what action should i take ?

Comment: Please share your code for furhter analysis. Without seeing the code, it is hard to say what is going wrong.